# Integral question rational functions?

Tags: integration

I have to find the integral of $\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}$. So I thought about writing it as $\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{(x+1)^2-1}}$ here I replace $x+1=u$ and I have $\frac{1}{u(u^2-1)}$ . What do I do next? The answer on my textbook is $-\arcsin[\frac{1}{x+1}]$.

Comment: Put $x+1=\sec\theta\implies x^2+2x=(x+1)^2-1=\tan^2\theta$

Comment: You forgot the square root in the denominator after the substitution.  I'm pretty sure I saw this same problem recently.  In any case, depending on how you do this, you may end up with several different correct forms.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the integral by using the $\sqrt{x^2+2x}=t- x$ as well.

Comment: Nice alternative!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: substitute $u = \sec{y}$, $du = \sec{y} \tan{y} dy$.  Then $u^2-1 = \tan^2{y}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution is good.  Now one can use a trigonometric substitution. But the substitution $u=\frac{1}{t}$ works very nicely. Then $du=-\frac{dt}{t^2}$, and after some minor algebra we arrive at the very familiar
$$\int -\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}},$$
and we are one step from the answer you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x+1=u$ and then $u=1/t$ 
$$\int \frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2-1}}=-\int \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=-\arcsin t +C$$
Thus
$$\int\frac{1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x^2+2x}}\mathrm{dx}=-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x+1}\right)+C$$

Comment: What I noted below as a substitution, will lead the integral to an integration of quotient function which is less beautiful. Yours is much practical and the Andre's also. +1

Comment: @BabakSorouh: thank you! I'm glad you like my answers! :-)